# How to paginate using CompositeDataBoundControl in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, pagination

It seems not many people are using `System.Web.UI.WebControls.CompositeDataBoundControl` which is from `System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataBoundControl`.
Has anyone worked with `CompositeDataBoundControl` with paginate?
I need some resources.